# Probability distribution function for biased coin until heads or tails occurs twice

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

There is a biased coin,
$P(H) = \frac{1}{3}$. It is tossed until heads or tails occur twice. Random variable X is number of tosses. Find the probability distribution function, f(x) of X.

I know 
S={THT,TT, HTH, HH, THH, HTT}

but $f_{x}(2)$ has 2 possibility Also $f_{x}(3)$ has 4 possibility. How can I calculate probability distribution function?

Comment: What happened to THH and HTT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Did](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/6179/did) mentioned in the comment you have forgotten two events: $THH$ and $HTT$.

Now you can calculate for each event the probability: In the cases of 3 tosses the single probabilities are:

$$P(THT)=\frac23\cdot \frac13\cdot \frac23, P(HTT)= \frac13\cdot \frac23 \cdot \frac23, P(HTH)= \frac13\cdot \frac23 \cdot \frac13, P(THH)=\frac23\cdot \frac13\cdot \frac13$$

Therefore $P(X=3)=P(THT)+P(HTT)+P(HTH)+P(THH)$

As you have already written the two events for two tosses are $HH$ and $TT$. Calculate these probabilities in the same manner like above and sum them up to get $P(X=2)$.

Then the probability distribution function looks like

$$f_X(x)=\begin{cases} \boxed{{\color{white}|\hspace{1cm}\color{white}|}} ,x=2 \\ \boxed{{\color{white}|\hspace{1cm}\color{white}|}} ,x=3 \\ 0, \texttt{elsewhere}\end{cases}$$

All it is left is to fill in the blanks with the corresponding values of $P(X=2)$ and $P(X=3)$. Remember that in this case $P(X=2)+P(X=3)=1$.

[Calculation](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cfrac23%5Ccdot%20%5Cfrac13%5Ccdot%20%5Cfrac23%2B%5Cfrac13%5Ccdot%20%5Cfrac23%20%5Ccdot%20%5Cfrac23%2B%5Cfrac13%5Ccdot%20%5Cfrac23%20%5Ccdot%20%5Cfrac13%2B%5Cfrac23%5Ccdot%20%5Cfrac13%5Ccdot%20%5Cfrac13%2B%5Cfrac23%5Ccdot%20%5Cfrac23%2B%20%5Cfrac13%5Ccdot%20%5Cfrac13)

Comment: Now, I realized There is 2 condition for X=3 because after TH and HT result of toss doesn't effect. So (2/3)*(1/3) for if first two results are TH in order and (1/3)*(2/3) for if first two results are HT in order. With your calculation sum of X=2 and X=3 makes 25/27 not 1

Comment: @Thereturn The cases for $X=2$ are $TT$ and $HH$. The corresponding probabilities are $\frac23\cdot \frac23$ and $\frac13\cdot \frac13$. If you sum up all single probabilities you will get $1$. Have a look at the calculation link in the answer.